# Proving $\zeta(2) - \beta(1) + \zeta(4) - \beta(3) + \zeta(6)- \beta(5) + \ldots=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Trying to prove

$$\zeta(2) - \beta(1) + \zeta(4) - \beta(3) + \zeta(6)- \beta(5) + \ldots=1$$
I found by numerical calculation that (when $k$ goes to infinity)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}\zeta (2n)=k+3/4+o(1),$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}\beta  (2n-1)=(k-1)+3/4+o(1).$$

in order to prove the above formula. Now how can I prove it analytically?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What definition of the Beta function are you using? The one I know depends on two parameters.

Comment: @rubik [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletBetaFunction.html](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletBetaFunction.html)

Comment: @whacka: Thanks!

Comment: I would suppose someone is working on a proof using the exponential generating function of Bernoulli and Euler numbers for the Zeta function / Beta function terms respectively even as I type this comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have:
$$\zeta(2k) = \frac{1}{(2k-1)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^{2k-1}}{e^t-1} \tag{1} $$
and:
$$\beta(2k-1)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^{2k-1}}=\frac{1}{(2k-2)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^{2k-2}e^t}{e^{2t}+1}\,dt \tag{2}$$
hence:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \beta(2n-1)\, z^{2n-1} = \frac{\pi z}{4}\cdot\sec\frac{\pi z}{2},\tag{3} $$
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \zeta(2n)\,z^{2n} = \frac{1-\pi z \cot(\pi z)}{2},\tag{4} $$
and:
$$ \lim_{z\to 1^-}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\zeta(2n)\, z^{2n}-\beta(2n-1)\, z^{2n-1}\right) = \color{red}{1}.\tag{5}$$

Comment: but numerically by using WolframAlph gives the $1$

Comment: ok Jack wait me to add some results in the question

Answer (score 0):

### $\underline{\left(1^{\text{st}}\right)\colon}$

$$ 
\begin{align} 
S&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(2n)\color{red}{-1+1}-\beta(2n-1)\right] \,=\color{Magenta}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(2n)-1\right]}\,+\,\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[1-\beta(2n-1)\right]} \\[4mm] 
\color{Magenta}{S_1}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(2n)-1\right] \,=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=\color{red}{2}}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{m^{2n}}\right] \,=\sum_{m=\color{red}{2}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^2-1} \,=\sum_{m=\color{red}{2}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(m-1)(m+1)} \,=\color{Magenta}{\frac{3}{4}} \\[4mm] 
\color{blue}{S_2}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[1-\beta(2n-1)\right] \,=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=\color{red}{2}}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(-1)^{m}}{(2m-1)^{2n-1}}\right] \,=\sum_{m=\color{red}{1}}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[{\small\frac{4m-1}{(4m-1)^{2n}}}-{\small\frac{4m+1}{(4m+1)^{2n}}}\right] \\ 
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left[{\small\frac{4m-1}{(4m-1)^{2}-1}}-{\small\frac{4m+1}{(4m+1)^{2}-1}}\right] \,=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{8m^2-2} \,=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\small 1/8}{(m-{\small 1/2})(m+{\small 1/2})} \,=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{4}} \\[4mm] 
\color{red}{S}&=\frac{3}{4}\,+\,\frac{1}{4} \,=\color{red}{1} 
\end{align} 
$$

---

### $\underline{\left(2^{\text{nd}}\right)\colon}$

$$ 
\begin{align} 
S&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[-\beta(2n-1)+\zeta(2n)\right] \,=-\beta(1)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty-1}\left[\zeta(2n)-\beta(2n+1)\right]+\lim_{\small n\rightarrow\infty}\zeta(2n) \\ 
&=\color{green}{\left[\lim_{\small n\rightarrow\infty}\zeta(2n)-\beta(1)\right]} +\color{Magenta}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(2n)-\zeta(2n+1)\right]} +\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(2n+1)-\beta(2n+1)\right]} \\[6mm] 
\color{Magenta}{S_1}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(2n)-\zeta(2n+1)\right] \,=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{m^{2n}}-\frac{\small 1/m}{m^{2n}}\right) \\ 
&=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)\left(\frac{1}{m^{2}-1}\right) \,=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m(m+1)} \,=\color{Magenta}{\frac{1}{2}} \\[6mm] 
\color{blue}{S_2}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(2n+1)-\beta(2n+1)\right] \,=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)\zeta(2n+1)\,-\,\Gamma(2n+1)\beta(2n+1)}{(2n)!} \\ 
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}-\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x}+1}\right)\left({\small\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}\right)dx =\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}-\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x}+1}\right)\left({\small\cosh{x}}-1\right)dx \\[2mm] 
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}-\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x}+1}\right)\left(\frac{e^{2x}+1}{2e^{x}}-1\right)\,dx \,=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(e^{x}+1)^2}{e^{4x}-1}\,\frac{(e^{x}-1)^2}{2e^{x}}\right)\,dx \\[2mm] 
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\,\frac{\small 1/2}{e^{x}}\right)\,dx \,=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x}+1}-\frac{\small 1/2}{e^{x}}\right)\,dx \,=\color{blue}{\beta(1)-\frac{1}{2}} \\[6mm] 
\color{red}{S}&=\left[\,\lim_{\small n\rightarrow\infty}\zeta(2n)-\beta(1)\,\right]\,+\,\left[\,\frac{1}{2}\,\right]\,+\,\left[\,\beta(1)-\frac{1}{2}\,\right] \,=\lim_{\small n\rightarrow\infty}\zeta(2n) \,=\color{red}{1} 
\end{align} 
$$

---

### $\underline{\left(\text{NB}\right)\colon}$

$$ 
\begin{align} 
\color{red}{S}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(2n)-\beta(2n-1)\right] =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\Gamma(2n)\,\zeta(2n)}{(2n-1)!}-\frac{\Gamma(2n-1)\,\beta(2n-1)}{(2n-2)!}\right] \\[2mm] 
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}\,-\,\frac{x^{2n-2}}{(2n-2)!}\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x}+1}\right]\,dx \\[2mm] 
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}\right)\,-\,\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x}+1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n-2}}{(2n-2)!}\right)\right]\,dx \\[2mm] 
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\sinh(x)}{e^{x}-1}\,-\,\frac{e^{x}\cosh(x)}{e^{2x}+1}\right]\,dx =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{e^{x}} =\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\,\rightarrow\,\{\mathcal{X}\,\,{\small\text{incorrect!}}\}} 
\end{align} 
$$